# How to query this JSONB column in postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, jsonb

So I have a table

```
Node_Mapping(location_id:UUID, node_ids: jsonb)
```

The corresponding POJO for this is

```
class NodeMapping{
    UUID locationId;
    Set<String> nodeIds;
}
```

Example data in table is

```
UUID1 : ['uuid100', 'uuid101']
UUID2 : ['uuid103', 'uuid101']
```

So I want to make a query like, **find out all the locationIds which contains 'uuid101'.**

Please help me to form the query.

Comment: `UUID1 : ['uuid100', 'uuid101']` isn't a valid JSON value, so it can't be stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) `?`

```
select *
from node_mapping
where node_ids ? 'uuid100';
```

This assumes that in reality the column stores a valid JSON array, e.g. `["uuid100", "uuid101"]` but not an invalid JSON like `UUID1 : ['uuid100', 'uuid101']`

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response! This indeed works great!
But I have another problem, If I use this with JPA, it gives me problem for parameters, since I cannot use it like 'where node_ids ? :aNodeId'. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: And this is what is stored in that column

[
    "73cd356d-bde6-491e-9f60-1d98308a4d6c",
    "ead7c66e-4088-448c-bf05-8d66b05e257d",
    "87cac7a6-06f8-48a5-b9d6-27eaf2d05646"
]